# Put input inside select

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to place an INPUT field inside select?

```
<select name="menu_files" class="form-control" >
    <option value="new_menu"> <input type="text"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Only text can go inside an option tag, no html. You'll have to create a custom solution.

Comment: Option tag takes only text and not other HTML elements. You cant insert an input box into a select drop down.

Comment: Will you be submitting this form using ajax? If so, you can make get a visual  result of a dropdown having a input field using Javascript

Answer (score 10):

### `<datalist>` Element

The `datalist` element is intended to provide a better mechanism for this concept.

```html
<input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
<datalist id="exampleList">
  <option value="A">  
  <option value="B">
</datalist>
```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<datalist>` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to place an INPUT field inside select. You can create your own custom plugin using jquery.
Try the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.dropdown a').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown').addClass("open");
  });
  $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function() {

    $('.dropdown-toggle b').remove().appendTo($('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text()));
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
}

.dropup,
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
  <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" id="drop2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select Country--<b class="caret"></b></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">USA</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">UK</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Russia</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Others <input type="text" id="other"/></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achive it putting the input tag "next to" and not "inside" the select tag but forcing them into a limited and fixed area like a table td.

```js
function selection(){
 var selected=document.getElementById("select1").value;
  if(selected==0){
   document.getElementById("input1").removeAttribute("hidden");
  }else{
   //elsewhere actions
  }
}
```

```css
td{
  width: 170px;
  max-width: 170px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input{
  width: 164px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="input1" hidden="hidden" placeholder="input data">
        <select onchange="selection()" id="select1">
          <option value="-1"></option>
          <option value="0">-make your own choice-</option>
          <option value="1">choice 1</option>
          <option value="2">choice 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdfclub/hbzkv40n/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also code like this.

```
<label class="text-left text-uppercase mt-1 sidenav-text w-100" for="category" onclick="menuShow();"  >Category</label>
        <p id="demo"></p>
```

and in remaining js

```
<script>
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    function menuShow(){
        demo.innerHTML = `
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Women<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Men<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Kid<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Boy<br>    
        `;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).