# How can I insert this input Search Inside Option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML with the following Input SearchBox and the Following Label that contains this Select Option.

I want to place the searchBox inside the Option so If I have 10000 This in that Select. To use the searchBox and select what option I want from there.

```js
searchBox = document.querySelector("#searchBox");
countries = document.querySelector("#btd1");
var when = "keyup"; //You can change this to keydown, keypress or change
searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
 var text = e.target.value;
 var options = countries.options;
 for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var option = options[i];
  var optionText = option.text;
  var lowerOptionText = optionText.toLowerCase();
  var lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
  var regex = new RegExp("^" + text, "i");
  var match = optionText.match(regex);
  var contains = lowerOptionText.indexOf(lowerText) != -1;
  if (match || contains) {
   option.selected = true;
   return;
  }
  searchBox.selectedIndex = 0;
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
 <input id="searchBox" placeholder="Seach Project..." type="search">
  <select id="btd1" name="Project">
       <option disabled hidden="" selected value="">
        Select Project *
       </option>
      </select>
            </body>
            </html>
```

The Option Box don't contain nothing cuz In my index it has a JS that Adds options with a add button.

Can anyone tell me please how can I make this work ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: *select*s aren't supposed to have this behavior. Consider using a dropdown menu instead

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810045/put-input-inside-select

Answer (score 1):

yeap, Here is your [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=7ca2c5342b8afccf725419647f5a907a). What I have done is this; Get the value of the searchbox dynamicly onkeyup then count the number of options included. then get into a for loop to get the best macth and write it into the select. Of course then break when there is a match to prevent the loop go and check other matches and come with a result with less match but a match.

Comment: I understand but I want that search inside the drop-down. If I push the drop-down button that search box is the first thing I see at the top

Comment: Then you should use some kind of JQuery plug-ins I belive.

Comment: Mate this is not select and options this is autocomplete Plug-in. This is not the way to achive this.

Comment: To do this, You need this plugin or you need to code it with ajax-php-mysql-jquery.

Comment: I need something Like that. Not that

Comment: Learn to use this plug-in otherwise you really need to write bunch of codes belive me. I'have done it in my webpage and its about 200lines of jquery only for keyup function and grabbing the pressed button to move up and down over the suggestions etc.

Comment: I found the exact thing I want https://select2.org/searching   . Down at matching Grouped Options is the Drop-Down I want and the search Box in it

Comment: And it explains it as I see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156095/discussion-between-andrei-ref-and-guney-saramali).