# Putting inputs and a button in a drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, button

In an angular project, I have 4 inputs the user should type in, and a `Set All` button which sets them.

[image]

How can I put this the input fields and the button to a drop-down menu with the headline `Fill inputs`?

This is the HTML code -

```
          <input type="number" placeholder = 'Chapter'  #chapter>
          <input type="number" placeholder = 'Page'  #page>
          <br>
          <input type="number" placeholder = 'First version'  #version1>
          <input type="number" placeholder = 'Second version'  #version2>
          <button type="submit" (click) = "setChapter(chapter.value);setPage(page.value);setV1(version1.value);setV2(version2.value);">Set All</button>
```

I'm looking for smething like that -

[image: Dropdown Example]

Just instead of buttons, it will contain input fields and a Set button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little research and found this link 
[Put input inside select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810045/put-input-inside-select)

Basically, there's no way to doing this natively in HTML. I would look into using a library like bootstrap, that has already built this sort of functionality. Check out this link and maybe it will help. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-forms

Edit: Since you're using angular. 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples#form