# How to set default value for input inside select option

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, html-select, html-input

Hello Guys I Have select and many options and i have input inside on of these options and i want to set default value for it. My Code is bellow

```
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    
    <select name="cars" id="cars" class='select2'>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  
    </select>
```

i want to set default value for `input id = 'searchfor'.`

i tried this code bellow but it doesn't work

```
   <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <input id='searchfor' type='search' value='car1' placeholder='search for your car'>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      
        </select>
```

when i open the select i don't see the value for this input

Comment: Are you sure thats even valid html?  I'm not?

Comment: No I Want In Laravel

Comment: This is called html.  It is what web pages are made from.  They are not made from Laravel

Comment: This is from laravel blade

Comment: so what?  It still needs to be valid html

Comment: it's vaild. what is not vaild

Comment: oh i'm sorry i have a mistake i'w correct it wait me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247396/discussion-between-laravel-and-snapey).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an text input element inside a select element

Using MDN as a reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select the only **permitted content** for a select element is;

> Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.

So it is not valid html for a select input element to itself contain an `input` element

See also for info;
[Put input inside select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810045/put-input-inside-select)

Comment: i delete the input and add bootsrap class `select2`

Comment: If this is a duplicate of another question, please flag it as a duplicate; don't leave a link to the other question as an incomplete answer.